# Storing data in any file using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, embedded, cordova-plugins, iot, hybrid-mobile-app

I have written a mobile application to fetch Accelerometer data from TI CC2650STK in evothings. I am thinking of storing the data in some text file if I am offline and then when I come online the app will forward that data to my server. 
**Is it possible? If yes How???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it via cordova-plugin-file. Attached is the link
[cordova-plugin-file usage](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_file_system.htm)